# Iterate set in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this models:

```
class House(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class BedRoom(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Catalog(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  house = models.ForeignKey(House)
  bedroom = models.ForeignKey(BedRoom)
```

at admin.py Catalog is inline to House

```
class CatalogInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Catalog

class HomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inline = [CatalogInline]
```

then I need obtain at view the list of Bedrooms from House Catalog, at Home model I have:

```
def bedrooms(self):
  return self.catalog_set.all()
```

but when I do at template obtaining "houses" from a view:

```
{% for house in houses %}
  {% for h in house %}
    <p>{{h.name}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get an error:
'Catalog' object is not iterable

what I'm doing wrong?

I should define the model in a different way?

Comment: how do you add your context data ?

Comment: I solve my problem redesign the models and this should be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, you don't seem to actually be calling the `bedrooms` method. I guess (and it is just a guess) you mean this:

```
{% for house in houses %}
  {% for h in house.bedrooms %}
    <p>{{h.name}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `bedrooms` method is pointless though, as you can just as easily do this:

```
{% for house in houses %}
  {% for h in house.catalog_set.all %}
    <p>{{h.name}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```